# How to write multiple argument function in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a function that does basic calculation in bash using bc command.

So far I have done this:

```
function bcl () { bc -l <<< \"$*\"  ;}
```

I want the output:

```
 # I get this easily
 bc -l <<< '5*6'
 # I get output 30
 # now I like to have
 bcl 5 * 6

 # gives the answer 30.
```

But this does not work. How can we fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the parameter expansion, not add quote characters:

```
bcl() { bc -l <<< "$*"  ;}
```

I removed the `function` keyword because, although bash allows it, it is non-standard.